# Rate limiting ICMP flood with nftables

Tags: nftables

I'm trying to figure out how to allow ICMP pings to a server with nftables without being subject to flood attacks.

Here's my initial config:

```
table inet firewall {
    chain incoming {
        type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop;

        # established/related connections
        ct state { established, related } accept

        # ICMP
        ip6 nexthdr icmpv6 icmpv6 type { destination-unreachable, packet-too-big, time-exceeded, parameter-problem, echo-reply, nd-router-advert, nd-neighbor-solicit, nd-neighbor-advert } accept
        ip protocol icmp icmp type { destination-unreachable, router-advertisement, time-exceeded, parameter-problem } accept

        # ICMP ping dealt with separately to rate limit
        ip6 nexthdr icmpv6 icmpv6 type echo-request limit rate 1/second accept
        ip protocol icmp icmp type echo-request limit rate 1/second accept
    }
}
```

However, flooding with `ping -f [IP_ADDRESS]` shows most packets getting through. Certainly more than one per second.

If I remove the `ct state { established, related } accept` rule I get 99% packet loss when trying to flood.

So it seems like the first request establishes a connection and subsequent pings ride in on that rule and it doesn't seem to matter if I put the `ct` rule after the `icmp` rule.

Any way to allow established connections but still rate limit pings?

Comment: Have you tried `tc`? You can throttle an interface or limit the rate.

Comment: @Tux_DEV_NULL, what is this `tc` you speak of? I don't see any mention of that in the docs. https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Quick_reference-nftables_in_10_minutes#Matches

Comment: tc is traffic contron in linux: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Traffic-Control-HOWTO/intro.html and http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Traffic-Control-HOWTO/software.html#s-iproute2-tc

Answer (score 3):

Try this solution:

```
table inet firewall {
    chain incoming {
        type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop;

        # ICMP ping dealt with separately to rate limit
        ip6 nexthdr icmpv6 icmpv6 type echo-request limit rate 1/second accept
        ip6 nexthdr icmpv6 icmpv6 type echo-request counter drop
        ip protocol icmp icmp type echo-request limit rate 1/second accept
        ip protocol icmp icmp type echo-request counter drop

        # established/related connections
        ct state { established, related } accept

        # ICMP
        ip6 nexthdr icmpv6 icmpv6 type { destination-unreachable, packet-too-big, time-exceeded, parameter-problem, echo-reply, nd-router-advert, nd-neighbor-solicit, nd-neighbor-advert } accept
        ip protocol icmp icmp type { destination-unreachable, router-advertisement, time-exceeded, parameter-problem } accept

    }
}
```

You should explicitly drop the packets, those exceeded ratelimit, to prevent accept they by rules below.

Answer (score 0):

Late, but I just stumbled over the same problem and google has led me here... the problem is indeed that ICMP echo/reply is handled by `conntrack`, see https://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/chunkyhtml/x1582.html.

You can use something like `watch -n1 conntrack -L` to supervise the contents of the connection tracking table in real time (default only shows IPv4, IPv6 can be shown via `-f ipv6` option)

The important thing is that you have to formulate the limiter as an `over` condition, where stuff gets `drop`ped **before** the `ct state` statement **and** blanket accept the incoming ping request **after** the connection tracking statement as well.

What this does:

- the first incoming ICMP request packet ("NEW" in ct lingo) is accepted via the normal rule
- all follow up packets of the "ESTABLISHED" ct state are allowed by connection tracking
- but all packets still have to pass the `limit rate over ...` rule first, so the limiter still works as expected

code:

```
   table inet firewall {
            
       chain incoming {

            type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop;
            
            # icmp echo rate limits
            ip6 nexthdr icmpv6 icmpv6 type echo-request limit rate over 1/second drop
            ip protocol icmp icmp type echo-request limit rate over 1/second drop


            # established/related connections
            ct state { established, related } accept
    

            # accept ICMP ping

            ip6 nexthdr icmpv6 icmpv6 type echo-request accept
            ip protocol icmp icmp type echo-request accept
        }
   }
```