# How do I limit ping (ICMP) responses on a debian 10 server?

Tags: linux, debian, ping, ddos, icmp

I have a VPS with debian 10 installed, primarily used for website hosting. when I issue a ping to the server from a remote machine, I am able to and receive responses for packet sizes up to around 64Kb using `-s 65507` flag. using `sudo` also enables me to increase the default ping maximum frequency from 5 per second using the `-i` flag. as the `man ping` page states, this is plausible behaviour.

what I would like to know is on the server, how can I limit ping responses to e.g. maximum x responses per second and maximum y Kb packet size? so that the command following command should NOT be possible:

`sudo ping example.com -s 65507 -i 0.001`

that is, "send 1000 64Kb pings to example.com every second".

which would flood the server with 64Mb/s worth of pings, all of which are being answered (albeit with a backlog) and reported back to the ping-issuing remote machine. I repeat, I do NOT want this to be possible for obvious reasons. despite having a basic firewall and fail2ban I am astonished this is possible at all and permissible with default config settings.

I have googled to no avail - nearly all results are for issuing the ping itself, there is nothing on how to limit responses on the target server. I have also tried changing `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_ratelimit` to a lower value than `1000` ICMP packets per second, but this appears to have no effect, even when reboot-proofing in `/etc/sysctl.conf`.

ideally, I would like to set a maximum interval of 0.5 seconds and a maximum packet size of 32 bytes, which I feel is perfectly adequate and reasonable for the purpose of pinging, i.e. checking connectivity and latency. by doing this it would defend against ping flooding, which is a big concern, because as it stands at the moment the server is prone to DoS attacks through this ICMP vector.

do I need some other tool or software, or am I missing something?

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Examples of rate limiting ICMP via firewall exist. nftables wiki, [Rate limiting matchings](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/). Server Fault, [Rate limiting ICMP flood with nftables](https://serverfault.com/q/877862/241174)

However, a host firewall is not a complete solution if bandwidth is saturated. The kernel needs to get the packet before it can be dropped. More complete denial of service protection needs to be earlier, through a service with more bandwidth than the attackers.

Comment: would than mean a service such as cloudflare?

Comment: Any DoS filter before your host. Firewalls, specialty DoS protection services.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to change `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_ratemask` as well. By default the limit does not apply to echo replies. See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/icmp.7.html